# IronPython - error while invoking

Tags: .net, com, interop, ironpython

Im trying to write an IronPython app that uses a COM object interface. I manage to import it using `clr.AddReference`, and manage also to call some of the functions, create objects, etc.

However at a certain point when trying to call a function I get :

> StandardError: Error while invoking GetK300RZ.

(GetK300RZ being the function name.)

Why is this happening to me? What does this error mean exactly? could this be related to the 'embed interop types' option?

I would greatly appriciate any insight as to how to get around this problem...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just for anyone who ever runs into this question with a similar problem - the problem was that the parameters of the functions were of type `out` and `ref` in `C#`. The function could not be invoked because there was no corresponding function signature. I had to use `clr.Reference[]` to explicitly create references for the function parameters.

I guess when using an external COM objects one should stop thinking python and start thinking .net or C#...